# check an input numeric variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to check an input numeric variable, this is an example... why it doesn't work? is there an alternative solution in jquery with method onchange without to use a button?

```
<input type="text" id="prova"> </input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()">

<script language="javascript">
     function test(){
        var x = document.getElementById("prova");
        if (x<=10)
            alert("è minore di 10");
        else
            alert("è maggiore di 10");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: `<script language="javascript">`? Why are you writing HTML 3.2 in 2014?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following JQuery code :

```
var x =$("#prova").val();
x = x.parseInt(x);
if(x<=10)
    alert("è minore di 10");
else
    alert("è maggiore di 10");
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 var x = document.getElementById("prova");
```

it will give the DOM object with id `porva`. You are comparing that DOM object with number, Use the value property of DOM object.

Change it to

```
 var x = document.getElementById("prova").value;
```

better to convert the value in number, because `.value` returns a string

```
 var x = +(document.getElementById("prova").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the results of stringifying the element (i.e. `"[Object object]"`) instead of its `.value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 var x = document.getElementById("prova");
```

use

```
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("prova").value,10);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<input type="text" id="prova"> </input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()">

<script language="javascript">
     function test(){
        var x = +(document.getElementById("prova").value);
        if (x<=10)
            alert("è minore di 10");
        else
            alert("è maggiore di 10");
     }
</script>
```